# Spring boot validation - appointment scheduling

Tags: spring-boot, validation, scheduling, appointment

Need a help how can I do validation for appointment booking ..patient can book appointment only once on that particular time

Eg. If patient book appointment from 3 o clock to 4 o clock same patient should not book appointment within that time

I am using spring

Answer (score 0):

You could model something like this:

[image: Relationship between Person and Appointment]

Person can have the Profession 'Doctor' which is the one who attends the appointments, or could be 'Patient' which is the one who ask for the appointments.

The other entity 'Appointment' is the one in charge of store one appointment at a certain datetime. This appointment is associated with two persons, one of them must be doctor and the other one must be patient.

By this way, you can ensure that there is only one appointment with one date by establishing the date as unique (for example)

Comment: Can you please explain as i already have table like the same where doc can create any number of appointment and patient too can book